# Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.67:devserver

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Hey i have a problem starting my maven project on devserver and update calls.
I buils my maven project to run with google cloud engine, but im getting this issue and cant start my server.
This is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <groupId>trainingBuddyServer</groupId>
  <artifactId>Training-Buddy-Server</artifactId>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
  </properties>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.5</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.67</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.67</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.67</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
      <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
      <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
      <artifactId>endpoints-framework-auth</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.67</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.67</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-tools-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.67</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
      <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
      <version>0.33</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.19</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.67</version>
        <configuration>
          <appId>trainingbuddy-221215</appId> <!-- Override appengine-web.xml <project> -->
          <version>1</version>
          <fullScanSeconds>1</fullScanSeconds>
          <retainUploadDir>true</retainUploadDir>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
           <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
           <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.1</version>
           <configuration>
              <deploy.promote>true</deploy.promote>
              <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-maven</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>3.5</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>
                <requirePluginVersions>
                   <message>Best Practice is to always define plugin versions!</message>
                   <banLatest>true</banLatest>
                   <banRelease>true</banRelease>
                   <phases>clean,deploy,verify,appengine:run,appengine:deploy,appengine:update,appengine:devappaserver,site</phases>
                </requirePluginVersions>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I think its something wrong with pom file, because error says that it cant find this element "com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.67:devserver". So this is teh error if it will help :

```
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.67:devserver (default-cli) @ Training-Buddy-Server ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.212 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-01T23:37:27+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.67:devserver (default-cli) on project Training-Buddy-Server: The parameters 'project' for goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.67:devserver are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

Maybe someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the

```
    <project>YOUR PROJECT ID</project>
```

Indeed solves it for me also, however I'm not using the newer gclod maven plugin but the older appengine one:

```
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

vs mine

```
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

At some point I should probably move on to the gcloud plugin but right now I haven't got time.

The old appengine plugin also works with the (undocumented) "project" configuration tag. Really confusing and also poor work by google since their getting ([started examples](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven)) doesn't work, from 1.9.67 and above. Also if it's required from now on we should have gotten some information about it.

For the record I'm posting my multi module/services parent pom snippet including the pluginmanagement with the old appengine plugin:

```
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
              <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
              <configuration>
                  <project>YOUR PROJECT ID</project> <!-- WHAT DO WE NEED THIS FOR-->
                  <jvmFlags>
                      <jvmFlag>-Ddatastore.backing_store=${project.basedir}/local_db.bin</jvmFlag>
                  </jvmFlags>
                  <fullScanSeconds>-1</fullScanSeconds>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you manage to solve this? I've been using my multi module project pom(s) for at least 3 years with no problems, however since 1.9.67 I'm no longer able to deploy or running devserver via appengine maven plugin, with the same error:

***The parameters 'project' for goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.67:devserver are missing or invalid***

Using 1.9.65 works for me, so as a short time solution you should be able to use that version instead, however I don't know how old versions your allowed to deploy.

Comment: Thanks downgrading version helped me!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with latest AppEngine. It worked fine with lower than 1.9.64, but it generated the same error with the later version. Today I solved that issue by adding  filed on the pom.xml as

```
  <plugin>
       <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
       <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.1</version>
       <configuration>
          <project>your project ID on Google Cloud </project>
          <deploy.promote>true</deploy.promote>
          <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem since 1.9.66:

> The parameters 'project' for goal
>   com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.66:... are missing or
>   invalid