# Regard to Java web application "heap space memory" Error, how to increase Google App Engine development server memory size?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk, devserver

To develop Google AppEngine web application, I normally test in the development server by using "mvn appengine:devserver". Whenever browsing localhost, the application shows OutofMemoryError as following. It may be the local_db.bin size is quite large than 1G memory as default in Google AppEngine development server. By using Eclipse Debug Configuration, it is available to increase the application's default memory size as follows. With these arguments, it works fine. The main development environment is a terminal, not Eclipse. Regard to this, can I have any solution to increase the memory size of the default devserver command in Google AppEngine Java SDK.

```
Exception in thread "Scanner-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[INFO]  at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.list(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.io.File.list(File.java:1122)
[INFO]  at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1207)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scanFile(Scanner.java:576)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scanFile(Scanner.java:580)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scanFile(Scanner.java:580)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scanFiles(Scanner.java:432)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
[INFO]  at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
[INFO]  at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

[Eclipse Debug Configuration]

[Program Argument]

```
--allow_remote_shutdown --disable_update_check --no_java_agent D:\xxx
```

[VM arguments]

```
-Xms2048m -Xmx8182m -Duse_jetty9_runtime=true  -D--enable_all_permissions=true   -Ddatastore.backing_store=D:\ocal_db.bin'
```

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the JVM options using the `jvmFlags` parameters as per this [documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven-reference#appenginerun)

If you include in the pom.xml it will look like this:

```
       <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.59</version>
        <configuration>
            <jvmFlags>
              <jvmFlag>-Xms2048m</jvmFlag>
              <jvmFlag>-Xmx8182m</jvmFlag>
            </jvmFlags>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

There was a discussion on this, you can take a look in this [answer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35901029#comment2)

Comment: Can you give another link, I guess it's Googler's internal only

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the link to the correct one: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35901029#comment2

Comment: Thank @dhauptman, you save my time. I have another issue regarding to GCP, can you follow up [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109943/failed-to-execute-goal-com-google-appengineappengine-maven-plugin1-9-67devser/53254667#53254667)

Comment: Even I insert the jvmFlags, it still has "heap space error". I cannot find jvmFlag in running script  as "C:\java -D--enable_all_permissions=true -Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=5 -Duse_jett
y9_runtime=true -classpath C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-java-sdk\1.9.64\appengine-java-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1
.9.64\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain --allow_remote_shutdown --no_java_agent D:\workspace
\app-1.0.0"

Comment: @steinen Sorry, you have to remove the <container> tag. I've updated the answer with the correct format.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked. I'm going to look at the other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109943/failed-to-execute-goal-com-google-appengineappengine-maven-plugin1-9-67devser/53254667#53254667) soon. Thanks for addressing this.

Comment: Regarding the other thread I've left a comment in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53270427/8456296). This is resolved in version 1.9.69. In this version you no longer need the <project> parameter.

Comment: When I use -Xmx8192m with 1.9.71 SDK version, it generates the error comment "Invalid maximum heap size" and "The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size", but it had no issue when built with 1.9.64. Can I know what the maximum VM size for google app engine is?